# How to tell if a group under multiplication is cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

For what reason are ($\mathbb{Z}_{8}^{\times}$, . ) and ($\mathbb{Z}_{12}^{\times}$, . ) not cyclic?

Maybe I'm not fulling understanding some part of this topic?

Comment: Cyclic groups, by definition, have a generator. Do any of the elements generate the whole of $\mathbb{Z}_{8}^{\times}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{12}^{\times}$ multiplicatively?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Determining the groups? Multiplying integers? It's hard to guess what help you need.

Comment: Do you know primitive roots?

Comment: @rschwieb Whoops, I missed the times in my notation. It's fixed now.

Comment: @BillWallis good thing we have the edit window :)

Answer (score 1):

Because they are both isomorphic to the Klein 4 group.

Now it's your turn to actually write down why.